# SWT table increment selection

Tags: java, swt

I am using a swt table and have implemented an `selectionListener`:

```
table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
       //...
    }
});
```

I click on the first item and the listener works!

Now, after pressing a button, I want to select the next item in the table automaticaly. I have tried:

```
table.setFocus();
table.select(table.getSelectionIndex() + 1);
```

and

```
table.setFocus();
table.setSelection(table.getSelectionIndex() + 1);
```

The selection changes (blue color), but the selectionListener does not react?!

Maybe you can help me with this issue.

Thank you for your help!

Kind regards

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's by design (cf. [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=153669)).

What you can do is the following:

```
table.setSelection(1);
table.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event());
```

---

Or even this:

```
table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
       methodCallHere();
    }
});
```

and then

```
table.setSelection(1);
methodCallHere();
```